# Modify an http request object so that it can be passed to a worker_thread

Tags: node.js, http, circular-reference, node-worker-threads

I have a server that performs some lengthy calculations. So I let the file called `parser.js` to be run in a worker thread.

Now, `parser` needs the http `request` object (from http module) because depending on the request parameters / body, `parser` may need to access different properties of `request`.

That's why I can't put specific parameters of the request in `workerData`. The properties `parser` needs is client determined.

A request object has functions AND it has circular references.

`JSON.stringify` won't work, and `workerData` can't have functions

I need to somehow remove the functions without destroying the circular references.

#### Solution tried

I came up with this

```
<file common.js>
 1 | const objectHistory = [];
 2 | function rmObjFunctions(obj) {
 3 |     for (const key in obj) {
 4 |        if ((typeof obj[key]).toLowerCase() == 'function') obj[key] = null;
 5 |        else if ((typeof obj[key]).toLowerCase() == 'object') {
 6 |            if (objectHistory.indexOf(obj[key]) != -1) continue;
 7 |            objectHistory.push(obj[key]);
 8 |            rmObjFunctions(obj[key]);
 9 |        }
10 |    }
11 |    return obj;
12 | }
```

The above function works for

```
const obj = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3',
    d: {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c() {
            console.log('Hi');
        },
    },
    e: '5'
};
obj.f = obj;
console.log(rmObjFunctions(obj));
```

Output

```
<ref *1> {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
  d: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: null },
  e: '5',
  f: [Circular *1]
}
```

#### It didn't work for the server

Code

```
const server = HTTP.createServer(function(req, res) {
    let statusCode = 200;
    let output = '';
    try {
        const workerData = {
            resource_root,
LABEL1:     req: rmObjFunctions(req),
        };
        const worker = new WorkerThreads.Worker(__dirname + '/parser.js', { workerData });
        const timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            worker.terminate();
            output += 'execution timed out after 10 seconds';
        }, 10000);
        worker.on('message', function([ statusCode, response ]) {
            res.statusCode = statusCode;
            output += response;
        });
        worker.on('error', function(error) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            output += String(error.stack);
        });
        worker.on('exit', function(exitcode) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            res.end(output);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
LABEL2: res.end(output);
    }
});
```

##### Error at `LABEL2`

The above code errors out at `LABEL2`, says `res.end isn't a function`. Running `typeof res.end` returns `object` instead of `function`.

Commenting out `LABEL2` causes error at `LABEL1`.

Indicates that `rmObjFunctions(req)` damaged the `response` object.

##### Error at `LABEL1`

```
node:net:731
  return this._getpeername().address;
              ^

TypeError: this._getpeername is not a function
    at Socket.remoteAddress (node:net:731:15)
    at rmObjFunctions (common.js:4:24)
    at rmObjFunctions (common.js:8:13)
```

##### Notes:

Modifying the http `request` object using `rmObjFunctions(req)` also damages the `response` object.

You can catch the above error as I've done, and then on the catch block, do `res.end()` and it'll tell you `end` isn't a function.

If you `typeof res.end` it'll output `object`, not `function`.

Comment: What do you mean by "damages the `response` object"?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't "destroy" anything (but yes, the very nature of serialization means it will necessarily _excludes_ function members and type information). But there's far more to host-environment-provided JS objects than just functions and symbols: JS hosts are able to embue potentially _anything_ with undocumented "magic" (yes, that's a technical term) which is completely invisible to the script running within, which is why it's important to not second-guess the host or use tricks like serialization.

Comment: Ah, sorry - that's my mistake. I had a brain-fart and thought your code was running in the browser, and you wanted to pass the request to a ServiceWorker, not NodeJS.

Comment: we should delete some comments